Can the integral inner product of finite dimensional real polynomial vector spaces be extended to infinite dimensional polynomial vector spaces?
I have only found sources saying that the spaces $\mathbb R_n[x]$ of polynomials of at most degree $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R$ have an inner product
$$ \langle p,q\rangle=\int_0^1 p(x)q(x)dx, $$
but can this be extended to the vector space $\mathbb R[x]$ of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb R$? I can't see why not, but I just want to make sure I understand it correctly. Here is my reasoning:
It is symmetric and bilinear because of symmetry and bilinearity of multiplication, and linearity of the integral. If $p\in\mathbb R[x]$, then $p^2\in\mathbb R[x]$, hence $p^2$ is zero at finitely many points, if $p\neq 0$. Thus the integral of $p^2$ must be positive which also proves positive definiteness.

It's just fine.

Yes, your inner product works for $\mathbb R[x]$.
